# Cube not square and being clipped horrendously, color doesn't apply

Tags: opengl, pygame

I'm trying to create my own object-oriented graphics library and use it to make a ping-pong game. I am following some tutorials online, and one uses old-style code with individual calls to `glVertex`, and the new stuff uses VBOs.

I have a project you can clone; it's available here:

https://github.com/awildtechno/ping

pingpong.py is the entry point. Run `pip install -r requirements.txt`, `python pingpong.py` to see the issue. The box seems to be deformed to the aspect ratio and it's clipping severely. It also doesn't use the color I passed in.

In line 31, if you switch VBOGameLoop for just GameLoop, you will get a nicely formed colorful cube using the same vertexes. There are a lot of trash files hanging out as a result of the switch, so I've cut out the code below. The relevant files are `Shape3D.py`, `Rect2D.py` `VBOGameLoop.py`, and of course `pingpong.py`.

This is a trimmed down version of the relevant PyGame/PyOpenGL code:

Setup:

```
# PyGame Init
pygame.init()
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.OPENGL)
pygame.display.set_caption('Ping Pong')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

drawables = {cube(1, Point3D(-.5, -.5, .2))}  # Point3D is just a wrapper for vectors.
glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH)
# glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST)
glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

# initial translation/camera angle
glTranslate(0., 0., -2)  
glRotate(0., 0., 0., 0.)
```

Main loop:

```
    gluPerspective(0, (display.get_width() / display.get_height()),
                   .05,
                   100.)
    glClearColor(.2,.2,.2,1) 
    # Main Loop #####################################
    self.exit_flag = False
    while not self.exit_flag:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type in self._event_handlers:
                self._event_handlers[event.type](self, event)

        # clear the screen
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        # Render all the things
        for d in self.drawables:
            verticies, shader, mode = d.to_renderable()
            vbo = VBO(verticies)
            try:
                # Add the VBO to gfxcard memory
                shaders.glUseProgram(shader)
                assert not glGetError()
                try:
                    vbo.bind()
                    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
                    glVertexPointerf(vbo)
                    glDrawArrays(mode, 0, len(verticies))
                finally:
                    # Release the VBO memory in the graphics card
                    vbo.unbind()
                    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
            finally:
                # Remove the shader
                shaders.glUseProgram(0)


        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(clock_rate)
```

Raw vertex data being passed into VBO:

```
[[-0.5 -0.5  0.2]
 [-0.5  0.5  0.2]
 [ 0.5  0.5  0.2]
 [-0.5 -0.5  0.2]
 [ 0.5  0.5  0.2]
 [ 0.5 -0.5  0.2]
 [-0.5  0.5  0.2]
 [-0.5  0.5  1.2]
 [ 0.5  0.5  1.2]
 [-0.5  0.5  0.2]
 [ 0.5  0.5  1.2]
 [ 0.5  0.5  0.2]
 [-0.5 -0.5  1.2]
 [-0.5 -0.5  0.2]
 [ 0.5 -0.5  0.2]
 [-0.5 -0.5  1.2]
 [ 0.5 -0.5  0.2]
 [ 0.5 -0.5  1.2]
 [-0.5 -0.5  1.2]
 [-0.5  0.5  1.2]
 [-0.5  0.5  0.2]
 [-0.5 -0.5  1.2]
 [-0.5  0.5  0.2]
 [-0.5 -0.5  0.2]
 [ 0.5 -0.5  0.2]
 [ 0.5  0.5  0.2]
 [ 0.5  0.5  1.2]
 [ 0.5 -0.5  0.2]
 [ 0.5  0.5  1.2]
 [ 0.5 -0.5  1.2]] 3 GL_TRIANGLES (4)
```

code for the shader:

```
    color=(.5, .5, .5, 1.0)
    # irrelevant stuff
        # Create the C code for the vertex shader.
        vshader = shaders.compileShader("""#version 120
        void main() {
            gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
        }""", GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        # Create the C code for the fragment shader.
        fshader = shaders.compileShader("""#version 120
        void main() {
            gl_FragColor = vec4""" + self.color.__str__() + """;
        }""", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        # Have openGL compile both shaders and save the result.
        self.shader = shaders.compileProgram(vshader, fshader)
```

I presume I'm misusing something about gluPerspective?

Comment: When asking for help with a graphics bug, always include a screen capture showing the bug.

Answer (score 0):

The clipping issue was solved with glLoadIdentity() before the perspective call.

The shader color issue was actually not an issue, I was passing in black like an idjit.